# The number of elements with certain value in list

Tags: prolog

I am trying to find out how many elements with value X are present in list that is passed as argument in prolog. My code is

```
cetnost(x,[],0).
cetnost(x,[X|T],C):- cetnost(X,T,C1),C is C1 + 1.


?- cetnost(a,[a,b,a,a],C).
         //false
```

Yet it keep returning false. What is wrong with this recursion? If empty list is passed C is set to 0 and recursive bubbling up with each bubling incrementing value by 1.

thanks for help

Comment: The problem is that you have x as input and you use capital X in the list and in the recursion. Change all to x and it will work.... Also in base case you don't need x just write cetnost(_,[ ],0).

Answer (score 1):

```
cetnost(_, [], 0).
cetnost(X, [X|T], C) :- cetnost(X, T, C1), C is C1 + 1, !. 
cetnost(X, [_|T], C) :- cetnost(X, T, C), !.
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides using an undercast `x`, which seems a typo, you don't have a case where the element you're looking for is *not* the head of your list.

You need something like

```
cetnost(X, [H|T], C) :-
   dif(X, H),
   cetnost(X, T, C).
```